# How to convert python-file to .exe one?

Tags: python, exe

How can I convert the .py file to .exe one? I don't want to use the `auto-py-to-exe`, `pyinstaller` and `nuitka` modules. They all give **too big** output file. Thanks everyone! And Google translator, thank you too! :)

I tried all these modules and expected them to make my programs faster, but it turned out not to be the case. The program began **7MB**, instead of **7KB**!

Comment: What leads you to believe that it should be 7kb?

Comment: The .py file is 7KB

Comment: The Python runtime is larger than your source code.  If you need to write code that compiles down as small as possible you might be better off with C, or even assembly, since those get you closer to the metal and let you prune out everything that’s extraneous.

Comment: I understand it. Sometimes I manage to rewrite a program in C++. But what if I want to make a program specifically in python?

Comment: Then you're going to have to deal with the file size.

Answer (score 0):

pip install pyinstaller (install PyInstaller)

(Once installed, you can use the following command to convert your Python file into an executable)

pyinstaller your_script.py

(x_Freeze is another library that can convert Python scripts into executables. It supports multiple platforms, including Windows, macOS, and Linux. Install cx_Freeze using pip)

pip install cx_Freeze

(Then, create a setup script that specifies your Python file as the target script. Run the following command to build the executable)

pip install cx_Freeze